# how to get html value pass to javascript or use two way binding by loopback?

Tags: angular

HTML:

```
<input #box (keyup)="0" value="" >
<p>{{box.value}}<p>
```

--> ok

javascript:

```
let i = {{box.value}}
```

--> fail
how to pass html values in here ??

I try to use n g model but failed

or how to use two way binding by loopback?

cause I need the input show in `<p></p>` realtime

Comment: there are too much error to fix , read this https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I know how to get and post value in html

Comment: But how to send the value into component?

Comment: Google mostly show me how to set a value in component and display in html

Comment: this is called binding

Answer (score 0):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="boxValue" >
```

in your code

```
...

boxValue: string;

...

doSomething() {
   let i = this.boxValue;
}
```